# How I can store my profile for permanent purpose?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, portable-apps

I would to have my profile when I move between systems, so I tried Firefox portable instead of Firefox and chrome portable instead of chrome.

They look good, but I'm missing what I'm looking for!  I want to be able to move my profiles so that I can go between computers with the same browser settings, and this data appears to be gone after I switch computers.

Comment: Enable sync on either

Comment: what system OS and computer brand, also logged in as what kind of user?

Comment: Actually I am on Win8. After sometime my login is passed away so I need to login again. it's worst then real version. What I thing is getting it for forever so I can use it even I move from my system to other.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the portable versions of browsers, the data is stored in the same folder as the portable application.

If you want to use this data, you'll have to start the application from the same place the next time (usually a portable device).

Also, the location where the portable application is stored must be writable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/)? It's a handy little utility that'll save all your Firefox settings to a backup file, and then you can store it wherever you want for later retrieval.

Comment: I have choose the portable version. what I need is saving my settings for forever so I can got the thing ready even I move from my system.